# CSS - window height

Tags: css

I have a #container element, that i have a background issue with:

```
html {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    height:100%;  
}


body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 12px;
    height:100%;
    background:url(/_images/body-bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    /*background:#0068b3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#bfd9ed), to(#0068b3));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bfd9ed,  #0068b3);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#bfd9ed', endColorstr='#0068b3')*/

}

#container {
    width:995px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;

}
```

When i add a background image to #container, and the page has content that requires scrolling, the background image only displays the amount of the window height, and when you scroll the background image does not display...

Why would that be?

Comment: try by removing `height:100%;
`

Comment: Try removing `no-repeat`

Answer (score 2):

To the image not scroll with the div, I must set it as fixed:

```
#container {
    background:url('img.png') top left no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed; //this will avoid scroll
}
```

In order to make the stretch the image to the size of the div, you can use `background-size: 100%;`, but this is a css3 property, and will not work in older browsers (IE8-)

If container will have a fixed width, just make a image with same width. Else, you'll have to implement a javascript solution to resize it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have `no-repeat` on the `background` CSS property of `body`.

Change to `repeat` or `repeat-y` to only repeat vertically.